# UTF8(stringToSign)

Tags: base64

```
Seems like I am not converting the following code from AWS docmentation correctly in Apex ? 

Signature = base64(hmac-sha256({accessKeySecret}, UTF8({stringToSign})))
```

**My conversion**

```
Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA256',blob.valueOf(stringToSign),blob.valueOf(secretAccessKey));


    string signature = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);
    string encoded = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(stringToSign, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translation is incorrect. The base-64 encoding applies to the final output. Just like in algebra, you have to resolve the enclosing parentheses first before the outer parentheses. It should look more like this:

```
String output = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(
  Crypto.generateMac(
    'hmacsha256', 
    Blob.valueOf(stringToSign),
    Blob.valueOf(secretKey) 
  )
);
```

The bit about "UTF-8" is superfluous in Apex, as all String values are already UTF-8. I've seen others suggest that EncodingUtil.urlEncode be used, but this is not correct.

See also my example of [AWS v4 authentication](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/92cf05807ac4becbd21f).

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox I will check out your example. Much appreciated